# This pattern matches for input 123456789.2.2.2 , which it should not

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to solve following task:

> Match the pattern abc.def.ghi.jkl, where each variable a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l can be any single character except the newline.

For above question I am matching the input to regex :

```
 "([^\\n]{3}(.)){3}([^\\n]{3})"
 // this is the regex pattern I am using currently
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me correct the above regex so that it does not match the incorrect input I have provided in the title. Currently it matches to it somehow. Although I have provided 3 it is apparently matching to more than 3 characters.

Comment: You need to also quote the `.` otherwise it matches any character.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve via `(.)`? Are you sure that this is correct way of doing it? What makes you think so?

Comment: But  i haven't used  \\ characters in front of . therefore it should work as a simple dot , shouldn't it ?

Comment: @vibhorvaish: *"therefore it should work as a simple dot , shouldn't it "* No, an unescaped `.` in a regular expression means "any character here."

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: @Pshemo can you unmark it ?

Comment: Please **don't** edit/change already answered question into entirely new one. Instead use ["Ask question"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and ask your [*new/separate*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74f5c212-dd93-4efa-bb54-ce6d300be1f1/view-source) question.

Comment: @Pshemo  I am unable to ask new questions due to negative reputation for this one. Is this how stackoverflow aims to help us ? At the time of asking this question, I didn't know that the above issue was due to \\. character , that's why I had asked new one and then it was marked as duplicate. Please suggest what to do here .

Comment: "I am unable to ask new questions due to negative reputation for *this* one" no, having one question with -1 vote is will not ban worthy. You most likely asked more questions which received worse score and now are deleted. Those are *also* included in score which counts toward question-ban. Anyway removing already answered question by changing it into new one defeats the purpose of this site which is gathering programming questions and answers so that *all* of us facing those problems could get help, not just asker.

Comment: What to do next is discussed at [Before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262), [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583).

Comment: I don't think this question is bad per se. Yes, you could avoid asking simple questions like these by using something like [an online regex tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html), but saying this question already has an answer in the _"regex meta dot vs literal dot"_ topic feels unfair ; if they knew the answer to the question was the dot thing, they wouldn't have asked the question. I'm grateful to the people who helped me with my bad questions back when I was a beginner. That said, I'm no expert with the SO guidelines, so I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` has a special meaning in regular expression patterns.

If you want to get a "simple dot", you need to quote/escape it (as `"\\."`).

And that special meaning is (under normal configuration) "any character except line breaks", which exactly matches your other condition, so you can simplify this to

```
"(...)\\.(...)\\.(...)\\.(...)"
```